Where to store user's files for confined apps?
The CherryTree software in strict confinment.
So, I can't save the file with the DB in my home directory. Where to save the DB file?
Now use Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, recently I used the previous version (23.x, as I remember). It's desktop. I installed CherryTree through App Center.

Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is this a desktop or server? How did you install cherrytree? Edit your question and add these information.

@user68186 Now use Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, recently I used the previous version (23.x, as I remember). It's desktop. I installed CherryTree through App Center.

So if I understand what you are trying to acheive you want to store files with CherryTree in a strict confinement environment on Ubuntu, you should use the Snap-specific directory where the application has write access. Here’s how you can do it:
Save Files in Snap Directory

Use Snap Directory:

Save your CherryTree database in the following directory:
~/snap/cherrytree/current/





Steps:

Open CherryTree:

When saving your file, navigate to ~/snap/cherrytree/current/.



If you prefer not to deal with sandbox restrictions, you can install CherryTree without sandboxing:
Install CherryTree Without Sandbox

Uninstall Snap Version:
sudo snap remove cherrytree
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cherrytree



